# Given a few dataframes, how can I transfer to the following format in python? Or is it even possible?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 samples of dataframes.

```
CategoryA df:           
colA    colB    colC    colD
a        a       a      nan
a        a       a      nan
a        a       a      nan
            
CategoryB df:           
colA    colB    colC    colD
a        a      a       a
a        a      a       a
a        a      a       a
```

I want to transform into as following.

```
category A  Description value
    colA    3a
    colB    3a
    colC    3a
    colD    0
    Total   9a
category B  
    colA    3a
    colB    3a
    colC    3a
    colD    3a
    Total   12a
```

Not sure if anyone has done this before, kindly ask if anyone has done this before please help.
Thanks

Comment: what if you have b in columns

Comment: @BENY yep it could happen, however, if we can solve the easiest, I can add more difficulty to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little diff than what you show

```
s = df.stack()
s = pd.crosstab(s.index.get_level_values(1),s,margins='index',margins_name='total').drop('total',1)
s
col_0  a
row_0   
colA   3
colB   3
colC   3
total  9
```